# MYSQL get all posts grouped by date

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, database

I want to get all posts in my database and have them returned, grouped by date (year -> month -> day -> posts for this day).

My current database structure:

`ID, author, title, content, created_at`

And possible values can be:

```
1, 1, "hello world", "This is the content", "2020-07-27 09:15:57"
2, 1, "Another post", "Another post content", "2020-07-27 11:09:55"
3, 1, "Third post", "No content", "2020-07-28 08:15:20"
...etc
```

What i want to achieve is, getting all these posts, but group them by date (year, month, day).
i.e.:

```
[2020] => [
   [7] => [
      [27] => [
         [ID] => 1,
         [ID] => 2,
      ],
      [28] => [
         [ID] => 3,
      ]
   ]
]
```

What i've tried so far:

`SELECT id FROM my_posts_table WHERE author = 1 GROUP BY created_at ORDER BY created_at ASC`

AND

`SELECT id, YEAR(created_at) as year, MONTH(created_at) as month, DAY(created_at) as day FROM my_posts_table WHERE author = 1 GROUP BY year, month, day ORDER BY year, month, day ASC`

My expected result would be the above example of what i want to achieve. But what i'm actually getting is:

```
[0] => [
   [ID] => 1,
   [year] => 2020,
   [month] => 7,
   [day] => 27
],
[1] => [
   [ID] => 3,
   [year] => 2020,
   [month] => 7,
   [day] => 28
]
```

I am completely confused at this moment because i thought 'GROUP BY' was working as i expected, but it appears to be working in a different way.

Can you guys point me in the right direction? I hope it's clear what i'm trying to achieve.
But if it's not, here is it again: "I want to get all the posts from my_posts_table where author_id = 1 and have them returned by year -> month -> day -> posts", So every post on day "27" should be under the [27] key..

EDIT: I made a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57e1e/1) as requested

Comment: Add sample fiddle (or at least CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts with sample data) and show desired output (MySQL output !!! not its JSON representation on the application side) for this data.

Comment: Let's say if you can get the output exactly how you want it, what you're going to do with it? Export to speadsheet (xls, xml etc.) or show it in a web page? or.. ?

Comment: @Akina i've added a SQLFiddle.

Comment: @tcadidot0 it is for displaying it on a webpage.

Comment: I think you just need to get the MySQL query right and design your webpage according to how you want it to look like. I'm guessing that's easier to do?

Comment: @tcadidot0 That's what this question is for. Getting the MySQL query right. How to display it on the page is easy as peanuts. Just getting the desired result is something i've been struggling to achieve

Comment: GROUP BY simply does not do what you expected it to. It _condenses_ multiple records that match the same grouping criteria, into a single one.

Comment: @CBroe i've noticed yes. But the question is, what is the correct way of getting what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: This isn’t really a job for the SQL query to begin with. SQL queries do not return “nested arrays”, they return records that _all_ have the same structure. Building the data structure you want, is processing that needs to happen _after_ you queried the data from the database, in whatever programming language you are using to further work on/with this result.

Comment: What you have shown as the desired result is impossible, btw. (assuming that was supposed to be a PHP array or something similar.) You can not have the key `ID` _twice_ underneath 2020 -> 7 -> 27.

Comment: @CBroe got it, so i'll check other possibilities.

Comment: If you replace the `ID` key on that level with a simple zero-based index, then the whole thing is fairly trivial to achieve in PHP. Just initialize an empty array, `$result = [];`, and then you loop over your records (selected without any GROUPing), and just add the IDs under the appropriate keys - `$result[$year][$month][$day][] = $id;`

Answer (score 0):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/)

For your SQLFiddle example try this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id), 
YEAR(created_at) as year, MONTH(created_at) as month, DAY(created_at) as day 
FROM my_posts_table 
WHERE author = 1 
GROUP BY year, month, day ORDER BY year, month, day ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

A database query always returns a "flat" resultset, made of rows and columns. If you want some a nested datastructure, then one approach is to write a scalar query, that returns just one rows and one column containing a JSON object.

This would involve several levels of aggregation, and JSON functions `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` and `JSON_OBJECT()`:

```
select json_object(created_year, json_arrayagg(obj)) obj
from (
    select 
        created_year, 
        json_object(created_month, json_arrayagg(obj)) obj      
    from (
        select 
            year(created_at)  created_year,
            month(created_at) created_month, 
            json_object(day(created_at), json_arrayagg(id)) obj
        from my_post_table
        group by year(created_at), month(created_at), day(created_at)
    ) t
    group by created_year, created_month
) t
```